# Ipython - %edit <functionname > throws error when notepad is opened

Tags: python, ipython, enthought

When I try to edit a function ( printval in my example ) defined in Enthought canopy Ipython using the command,

`%edit printval` .

I get the following error message on a pop up with a notepad opened in the background.

`The filename,directory name ,or volume label syntax is incorrect.`

The notepad is blank after I click the pop up message. This error is happening in windows Ipython.

Also I invoked Ipython using the following command

```
ipython qtconsole --pylab=inline --colors=Linux
```

Can anyone help to find what can be the problem .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works for me. Are you sure that the function name `printval` is already in your ipython namespace when you give the command `%edit printval`? You can check this by seeing whether `printval?` refers you to your function as expected, or gives an error. If `printval` isn't in your ipython namespace, then ipython has no way to know what you mean by `printval`.

For example, if you have already done `from mymodule import printval`,

then `%edit printval` should work.

If this doesn't address the issue, please provide a minimal example including all steps to reproduce the problem.

---

UPDATE after this followup information from user: " `File: c:\users\tester\<ipython-input-5-cc5d372a3507>`"

This shows that the function was not defined in a file as typically done, but rather interactively at the ipython prompt. This complicates the answer, thus:

When a function is defined in a (non-temporary) file, then `%edit functionname` works as desired in all versions of ipython - it opens that file for editing.

However when the function is defined interactively at an ipython prompt, as in this user's case, then the actual behavior depends on the version of ipython and which ipython/jupyter interface you are using. What one would like is for a temporary file to be opened, the function definition be copied into that file for editing, and then after the editor closes, for the function definition to be re-executed (i.e. for the function to be re-defined) based on those edits.

Indeed, this desired behavior is implemented in simple text-mode ipython terminal (e.g. if you type `ipython` at a Canopy Command Prompt).

However, this desired behavior has never been implemented in ipython/jupyter QtConsole (e.g. if you type `jupyter qtconsole` at a Canopy Command Prompt), and as far as I can tell, it is not currently planned by the jupyter team, most of whose effort seems to be focused on the jupyter notebook and jupyter lab projects.

Because Canopy is a GUI application, Canopy's ipython prompt is a QtConsole, not an ipython terminal prompt. Therefore Canopy does not implement the behavior that you want, and will not in the foreseeable future.

The (minor) good news is that in the most recent version of QtConsole, the error message is more explicit. It says "InteractivelyDefined" which at least gives a hint that the function that you were editing was defined interactively and is therefore not directly editable.

The workaround, of course, is to manually copy-paste the function definition source code into the Canopy editor (which automatically strips out the ipython prompts from the clipboard, making this very simple to do), edit the function there, and run that file.

Comment: when I execute the command which you said,   `%edit printval?`
I get the following information, which means it is available in namespace 
`Type:       function
String Form:<function printval at 0x00000000050195F8>
File:       c:\users\tester\<ipython-input-5-cc5d372a3507>
Definition: printval()
Docstring:  <no docstring>` I think it is something to do with settings of Enthought Canopy

Comment: I opened  Canopy Command Prompt and typed `ipython` and defined the following function `def printval(): print 'hello' ` .When I used the following command `%edit printval` I get the following error message : `editing...The syntax of the command is incorrect. Warning:could not open editor` . The Ipython version is 0.13.1 with python version as 2.7.3

Comment: "The Ipython version is 0.13.1 with python version as 2.7.3" If this is actually a Canopy Command Prompt then it is a very (>3 years) old version of Canopy, or is being blocked by another very old Python installation. To update Canopy to the latest version, please see [this article](https://support.enthought.com/entries/61798124-Canopy-shows-no-updates-available-reinstalling-from-the-website).

Comment: Makes sense.will try upgrading